# Find a combination with length n from an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, combinations, redundancy

I am building a big Algo. and I got stuck trying to code a helping algo.

I found some good examples in the Interner but all of them are missing a small and important detail:

I need to code a methode: `combine(int[] numbers, int n)`

`numbers` is an array of unique numbers, for example: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`

and `n` is the length of the combinations, for example: `n=3 -> [1,2,3] or [7,2,5]`

as simple example of the method:

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4}

System.out.println(combine(numbers,2))
```

the output should look like this:

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
3,4
```

its very important that redundant does not come out, such as: `1,2` and `2,1`
and also not same numbers such as `1,1` or `2,2`

the code that I found looks like this: (it does not remove redundant and that is my problem)

```
    public static List<int[]> combinations(int n, int[] arr) {
        List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // Calculate the number of arrays we should create
        int numArrays = (int)Math.pow(arr.length, n);
        // Create each array
        for(int i = 0; i < numArrays; i++) {
            list.add(new int[n]);
        }
        // Fill up the arrays
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // This is the period with which this position changes, i.e.
            // a period of 5 means the value changes every 5th array
            int period = (int) Math.pow(arr.length, n - j - 1);
            for(int i = 0; i < numArrays; i++) {
                int[] current = list.get(i);
                // Get the correct item and set it
                int index = i / period % arr.length;
                current[j] = arr[index];
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

and I did call it in main like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] current = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    List<int[]> s = combinations(2,current);
    for(int j = 0; j < s.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(((int[])s.get(j))[0] +"," +((int[])s.get(j))[1]);
    }

}
```

and the output looks the same like the one before but with more combinations and alot of redundants

how to edit the code above to get the output with out redundants?

Comment: Ok, and your question is...?

Comment: I edited the question, please check the last line

Comment: if the method creates what you want but with redundant pairs then just filter out the redundant pairs with another function before setting the List s. Do something like public static List<int[]> filterRedundantPairs(List<int[]>) and inside this method just loop through the list and remove the pairs.

Comment: I would do that, but I am out of ideas gow to do that, all pairs are save as array in a list, and if I found the pair 1,2 I need then to go throw the whole list to check if there is a 2,1 and delete it.. its not efficient. this is why I am asking.. ideas

Comment: Is this what you want? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n